# Java: if / else not responding even with no compile errors

Tags: java, if-statement, logic

I wrote a simple if / else that is supposed to print the answer to the if else.  but does not respond even with the correct input. I can't see what I'm missing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MarriageQuiz{
    public static void main(String[] args){   
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String marStat;
        System.out.print("Please enter your Marital Status (M or S) >> ");
        marStat = input.nextLine();
        marStat = marStat.toUppercase();            
        if(marStat.equals('M')){
            System.out.print("You are married");
        }
        else if(marStat.equals('S')){
            System.out.print("You are single");
        }
    }         
}
```

Comment: You need to compare `marStat`, a string, against another string, i.e. use `if (marStat.equals("M")) { ...}`

Comment: So I need to establish a second string then compare it?  I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: In Java, single quotes are a `char` and double quotes are a `String`. You are comparing a `String` to a `char` which will always be `false`.

Comment: Thanks for telling me the why.  It actually explains a lot as I started out with char in the code but found I didn't need it.  I forgot to adjust the quote marks.

Comment: The above is correct, but to add a bit more detail: in Java, chars (single characters enclosed in single quotes) are stored as primitives. Strings are objects. When you call marStat.equals('S'), you are attempting to compare a String object to  a char primitive. Under the hood, Java will autobox the char primitive to a Character object, which will fail comparison with a String. I'll add some tips in an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `""`

```
if(marStat.equals("M")){
        System.out.print("You are married");
    }
    else if(marStat.equals("S")){
        System.out.print("You are single");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is comparing a `String` object against a character literal, which I believe the JVM will box into a `Character` object.  Well, these two objects don't belong to the same class, so `"M".equals('M')` will return false.  To remedy this, use `"M".equals("M")`.

change `toUppercase()` to `toUpperCase()` and `marStat.equals('M')` to `marStat.equals("M")` also `marStat.equals('S')` to `marStat.equals("S")`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MarriageQuiz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String marStat = "";

        System.out.print("Please enter your Marital Status (M or S) >> ");
        marStat = input.nextLine();
        marStat = marStat.toUpperCase();

        if (marStat.equals("M")) {
            System.out.print("You are married");
        } else if (marStat.equals("S")) {
            System.out.print("You are single");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That fixed a problem I didn't know I had yet, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

On the other hand, you can use `Character` type instead of 'String'. Rather using `Character` would be more accurate as you are dealing with only one character.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

Character marStat;
System.out.print("Please enter your Marital Status (M or S) >> ");

marStat = input.next().charAt(0);
marStat = Character.toUpperCase(marStat);

if (marStat.equals('M')) {
    System.out.println("You are married");
} else if (marStat.equals('S')) {
    System.out.println("You are single");
}
```

Comment: Please note that although this is not really relevant to this particular case, Character.toUpperCase is not in general a good idea. See the specification: "In general, String.toUpperCase() should be used to map characters to uppercase. String case mapping methods have several benefits over Character case mapping methods. String case mapping methods can perform locale-sensitive mappings, context-sensitive mappings, and 1:M character mappings, whereas the Character case mapping methods cannot."

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment above, you are comparing a String object to an autoboxed Character object. One fix is obviously using double quotes, which Java will autobox to a String object your code will work.

A few tips to save a few lines of code: use String.equalsIgnoreCase() to save a line converting the incoming string to uppercase.

Next, consider using a constant for marital status:

```
public class MarriageQuiz{
    private static final String STATUS_MARRIED = "M";
    ...
    if (marStat.equalsIgnoreCase(STATUS_MARRIED)) {
    ...
```

That way you can use STATUS_MARRIED all over your code but can change it from, say, "M" to "Married" easily.